# Не сортируется список Python

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Всем добрый день! Возникла проблема с сортировкой списка. Требуется прочитать файл, разбить каждую строку на список слов, для каждого слова проверить, есть ли слово в списке, после завершения программы отсортировать и распечатать слова в алфавитном порядке. Не могу понять чем вызвана эта проблема, список сформировался, но сортировка по алфавиту не происходит.

```
romeo_append = []
romeo_open = open('romeo.txt')

for romeo_list in romeo_open: 
    romeo_split = romeo_list.split()
    if romeo_split in romeo_append:
       continue
    romeo_append.append(romeo_split)
    romeo_append.sort()

print(romeo_append)
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

> ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks',
> 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon',
> 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window',
> 'with', 'yonder']

А на деле он вот такой:

> [['Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon'],
> ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window',
> 'breaks'], ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the',
> 'sun'], ['Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with',
> 'grief']]

Comment: замените `romeo_append.append` на `romeo_append.extend`. И еще вынесите `sort` за цикл.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Заработало.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, в списке останутся дубликаты слов. А их быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы расширить список всеми элементами другого, используйте `+` или `extend`.

Аппендом же вы добавляете подсписок.

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что вы обрабатываете строки целиком (в виде списков) а нужно обрабатывать отдельные слова. Вот ваш код с минимальными изменениями:

```
romeo_append = []
romeo_open = open('romeo.txt')

for romeo_list in romeo_open:
    romeo_split = romeo_list.split()
    for word in romeo_split:
        if word in romeo_append:
            continue
        romeo_append.append(word)
romeo_append.sort()

print(romeo_append)
```

Но это решение не из быстрых если текст будет достаточно длинным. Вместо списка лучше хранить множество:

```
romeo_set = set()
romeo_open = open('romeo.txt')

for romeo_list in romeo_open:
    romeo_split = romeo_list.split()
    for word in romeo_split:
        romeo_set.add(word)
romeo_append = sorted(romeo_set)

print(romeo_append)
```

И если делать код совсем питоновским, то надо отделить перебор слов от их обработки:

```
def words(f):
    for line in f:
        yield from line.split():


with open('romeo.txt') as f:
    romeo_list = sorted(set(words(f)))   
print(romeo_list)
```

Comment: C filter() можно еще лаконичней написать.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014, как?